# Different results when using Manual KFold-Cross validation vs. KerasClassifier-KFold Cross Validation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, cross-validation

I've been struggling to understand why two similar Kfold-cross validations result in two different averages.

When I use a manual KFold approach (with Tensorflow and Keras)

```
cvscores = []
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=3)
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
  model = create_baseline()
  model.fit(X[train], y[train], epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
  scores = model.evaluate(X[test], y[test], verbose=0)
  #print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
  cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))
```

I get

```
65.89% (+/- 3.77%)
```

When I use the KerasClassifier wrapper from scikit

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True, random_state=3)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

I get

```
63.82% (5.37%)
```

Additionally, when using KerasClassifier the following warning appears

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py:241: Sequential.predict_classes (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential) is deprecated and will be removed after 2021-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
Please use instead:* `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`,   if your model does multi-class classification   (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).* `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`,   if your model does binary classification   (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).
```

Do the results differ because KerasClassifier uses *predict_classes()* while the manual Tensorflow/Keras approach uses just *predict()*? If so, which approach is more reasonable?

My model looks like this

```
def create_baseline():
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_shape=(12,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two CV-results do not look too different, they are both within each others standard deviation.

You fixed the seed for the `StratifiedKFold` class, that's good. However there is additional randomness you should take control of and that comes from the **weight initialization**. Make sure you initialize your model for each CV-run with different weights, but use the same 10 initializations for both cross-validations, manual and automatic. You can pass an [initializer](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/) to each layer, they have a `seed` argument as well. In general you should fix all possible seeds (`np.random.seed(3)`, `tf.set_random_seed(3)`).

What happens if you run `cross_val_score()` or your manual version twice? Do you get the same results / numbers?

Comment: Your're right, I just thought they would be exactly the same and not different.

I think I already did what you're suggesting: When I import all packages I also call
`from numpy.random import seed
seed(3)
from tensorflow.random import set_seed
tf.random.set_seed(3)`

Comment: Regardless, I also used the seed with the initializer and run them twice: Still different results. Would you prefer the manual since the _predict_classes_ will be depreciated at the end of the year? I will mark it as accepted as soon as you answer me that last one :)

Comment: If you plan to never update your libraries again or run your program only once, choose whatever you prefer. Otherwise I would highly recommend to use the manual one ;)

Comment: If you are really paranoid and curious whats the issue, print every intermediate step. Look splits, look at the weights returned from the initializer, look at the outputs for every episode, set `shuffle=Flase` in the `fit()` method. Basically fix everything you can and investigate.